# Sharing a proxy connection with 802.1X authentication

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, proxy, android, 802.1x

I want to start by saying that I'm really new at this, and I'm really looking forward to learning something but I don't know where to start.

The problem is this: I study at a university that has protected wi-fi and won't share it if not on their computers. So, the school has two wi-fi connections, one is for students (let's call this first one `Students`) and the other one is for workers (let's call it `Workers`). Both use WPA2-Enterprise (MSCHAPV2) authentication and also use a proxy. I have two computers: the first one is a Dell that was given me by the school and is connected to the `Students` network (they gave it to me already set up); the other one is my own MacBook Unibody that, using a workaround, I was able to connect to the `Workers` network.

Now, this is the problem: I recently bought an Android tablet that I need to connect to the internet, and when I connected it to the `Workers` connections (with the same method I used with the MacBook) I faced two problems:

1. the router is too far away and I can't get a good signal strength
2. The proxy setting on my tablet will work only for Chrome and won't apply to the application.

So, I was thinking about a way to fix this, and I finally had two ideas to make it:

1. Connecting one of my two laptops via ethernet and sharing the connection via wifi, avoiding the proxy setting (I have no idea if it is possible)
2. making the same thing, except that keeping the proxy and rooting my tablet in order to use the proxy settings in all my apps.

I also think it's not possible to share my connection using the MacBook since Mac OS X doesn't allow sharing 802.1X protected network by design.

What should I do?